# Terminal won't open with Hot Key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I have searched previous threads and found nothing that seemed pertinent.

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

All hotkeys are working, apart from Terminal. When I press ctrl + alt + t I expect terminal to open.

I've tried setting a different hotkey for terminal. That failed. I've tried adding a hotkey for a feature that previously had no hotkey. That succeeded. Have restarted also.
I am able to open terminal from the application menu

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any messages in syslog when you press the hotkey? e.g. `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal window then press the hotkey and see what (if anything) shows. For example, I get `Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.` then `Started VTE child process 789236 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 631168.`

Comment: Thanks! I get: `gsd-media-keys[17647]: 
sh: 1: exec: x-terminal-emulator: not found` and
 `Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys` and
 `systemd-timedated.service: Succeeded`   @codlord

Comment: o.k. so it looks like your issue is ` x-terminal-emulator: not found` either the gnome terminal (x-terminal-emulator) is not installed or something in your config means it can't be run. When you say you open terminal from the applications menu exactly what opens? Can you find a "About" option and see exactly what terminal and version is running. Maybe it's a different (non-standard) terminal program.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Q7TbV1S.png  is what I see when I open from the app menu. `_NET_WM_PID(CARDINAL) = 40231
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-terminal-server", "Gnome-terminal"` GNOME Terminal 3.36.2 A terminal emulator for the GNOME desktop
Using VTE version 0.60.3 +BIDI +GNUTLS +ICU +SYSTEMD  @codlord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we can see that the hotkey is trying to run `x-terminal-emulator` which is not found and your app menu terminal is running `gnome-terminal-server`

Try this command:

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`

Which should display a list of all installed terminal emulators and allow you to pick what you want to use as your default. If it shows `gnome-terminal` or `gnome-terminal.wrapper` then that's what you want to choose which should then set a symbolic link so running `x-terminal-emulator` runs your chosen terminal. Then hopefully the hotkey will work.

Comment: `update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator is dangling; it will be updated with best choice
There is only one alternative in link group x-terminal-emulator (providing /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator): /usr/bin/qterminal
Nothing to configure.`
@codlord

Comment: Not sure why it's saying qterminal is the only option when you obviously have gnome-terminal installed (I think qterminal is default Lubuntu terminal). I don't know the solution but if it were me I would try uninstalling and re-installing gnome terminal `sudo apt-get remove gnome-terminal` then `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: That worked! A few days ago I did reinstall gnome terminal so thats why I hadn't tried that option before. Thanks so much @codlord